# How to resolve this error when parsing string to double?

Tags: android, android-edittext, string-parsing

Im trying to get a String from a EditText and parse to a double. But I'm getting a error.

```
09-26 10:42:41.589: E/AndroidRuntime(17901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 10:42:41.589: E/AndroidRuntime(17901): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
09-26 10:42:41.589: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
09-26 10:42:41.589: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
09-26 10:42:41.589: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at br.com.going2.Checkincomercial.NovoCheckinActivity$4.onClick(NovoCheckinActivity.java:219)
```

code

```
String controle = "";
controle = etCustoNovoCheckin.getText().toString();
if( controle == null || controle == ""){
custo = 0.0;
} else {
custo = Double.parseDouble(controle);   
}
```

Comment: custo is float or double?

Comment: @BrijeshPatel `double` otherwise `custo = 0.0;` compilation error

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out:

```
                       if( controle.equals(null) || controle.equals("")){
                            custo = 0.0;
                        } else {
                            custo = Double.parseDouble(controle);   
                        }
```

The error was that I was not using .equals to compare the String.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `if` statement with:

```
if( controle == null || controle.trim() == "" || !controle.matches("\d+\.\d+|\d+")).
```

something like:

```
String controle = "";
controle = etCustoNovoCheckin.getText().toString();
if( controle == null || controle.trim() == "" || !controle.matches("\d+\.\d+|\d+")){
 custo = 0.0;
}
 else {
  custo = Double.parseDouble(controle);   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
                String controle = "";
                controle = etCustoNovoCheckin.getText().toString();
                if(controle.trim().length()>0){
                custo = Double.parseDouble(controle); 
                } 
                else {
                custo = 0.0;  
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your EditText-Box should only support numbers, set a EditText-Box attribute.

```
  android:inputType="number"
```

And you don't get into this "trouble"